# Is SQL Server Profiler different from SQL Trace?

Tags: sql-server, profiler, terminology

In this [source](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/) it is written something like this
[image]

I want to know what is SQL Trace? Does it refer here to Traces inside SQL Profiler or this is a different tool. I try to search it but can't find any resource. Thanks

Comment: According to MS Docs [SQL Server profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) is an interface to create and manage [SQL Traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-2017) and analyze and replay trace results.

Comment: SQL Trace = Server side trace which has low impact than running the profiler GUI. See my answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107510/8783.

Comment: An easy way to descrive `Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a graphical user interface to SQL Trace `. Source: Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a graphical user interface to SQL Trace.  FYI `SQL Trace and SQL Server Profiler are deprecated. The Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace namespace that contains the Microsoft SQL Server Trace and Replay objects are also deprecated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the picture below you see how SQL Trace collects Traces about events and one way to view those events is through SQL Server Profiler. So, they are phases in same process, making different task each.

Note from first link:

> SQL Trace and SQL Server Profiler are deprecated. The Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace namespace that contains the Microsoft SQL Server Trace and Replay objects are also deprecated.
>
> This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
>
> Use Extended Events instead.

For Extended Events, look my last link.

[image: architecture]

**Sources:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/create-a-trace-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-2017